# How can I rank observations within groups in Stata in descending order?

Tags: stata

I have district level data grouped within town level data with voter turnout. I want to regroup or rank the towns with highest voter turnout in each district.

Answer (score 7):

To rank in descending order, just negate the variable (or more generally the expression) on which you are ranking.

```
 sysuse auto 
 egen rank = rank(-mpg)
```

Stata's default is to rank in ascending order. But a minus sign is sufficient to reverse that.

In your case, it sounds like

```
 egen rank = rank(-turnout), by(district)
```

Comment: What is the history behind Stata, a data manipulation software, not having a sort descending option? This seems like a pretty basic oversight.

Comment: The generality is there by being able to rank on expressions. If you look at the documentation for the `rank()` function of `egen`, what is missing that you might want? If you're saying that the function should have an explicit `descending` option, that is an expression of taste.